# estimate the average value group by a specific column using python

Tags: python, numpy, average

I have an ascii file containing 2 columns as following;

```
id value
1  15.1
1  12.1 
1  13.5
2  12.4
2  12.5
3  10.1
3  10.2
3  10.5
4  15.1
4  11.2
4  11.5
4  11.7
5  12.5
5  12.2
```

I want to estimate the average value of column "value" for each id (i.e. group by id)

Is it possible to do that in python using numpy or pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how to read the file, there are several methods as you can see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) that you could use, so you can try one of them, e.g. `pd.read_csv()`.

Once you have read the file, you could try this using pandas functions as `pd.DataFrame.groupby` and `pd.Series.mean()`:

```
df.groupby('id').mean()

#if df['id'] is the index, try this:
#df.reset_index().groupby('id').mean()
```

Output:

```
        value
id           
1   13.566667
2   12.450000
3   10.266667
4   12.375000
5   12.350000
```

Comment: thank you, in case I have more than two columns and I want to get the mean of column 'value', how I could define this?

Comment: you could try with `df.groupby('id').mean().val`, since when you're using `groupby` an then applying a function, if maybe the other columns are of type str, the function will not be applied. But to be more precise, you could try this: `df.groupby('id').val.mean()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "data.txt"
df = pd.read_fwf(filename)
df.groupby(['id']).mean()
```

Output

```
        value
id           
1   13.566667
2   12.450000
3   10.266667
4   12.375000
5   12.350000
```